# Throwing cubes in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

On the xbox version of Portal 2, I was wondering if there was a way to throw cubes. I believe you can on the computer, but there's nothing about the xbox...

Comment: Like running and pressing the RB button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both PC and console, **I believe you can't**, the grabbing system has changed since Portal 1, where you could either **free** or **throw** (free : grab key, throw : primary fire). Now it's a bit trickier, because **you have to make a swing** in order to throw your cube. The swing-release is possible because with a mouse, you control the position of the view, which means you can go as fast as you want it to go and instantly release. With a gamepad, however, you control the angular velocity of the view (which is why a mouse FPS player has advantage over a gamepad player : he can just blink his sights on the target, with a negligible travel time, whereas the gamepad user *needs* the travel time to be accurate in stopping at the right time), which means that you have to trade maximum speed for accuracy. Usually this results in a maximum speed way too low to make a cube throw. Try to **boost your view axis sensitivity** and see what you can do.

I'm guessing they removed it because you could hack certain puzzles by getting a lucky throw (which was used in many Portal 1 speedruns).

Another reason would be the nature of the grabbing : a Zero Point Energy Field Manipulator like in Half-Life, except without the energy pulse ? Because a ZPEFM + portals would be too much for a single device, but they needed to manipulate stuff without having to code the player hands, and the ZPEFM is a good scenaristic pirouette to justify it.

I hope this helps, if you want a shorter answer, here it is : it is unlikely that you can effectively throw cubes on console, not because of a difference in game code but in the limits of the controller.

Comment: Thank you! After trying, I was not able to throw after increasing the sensitivity. I might try the demo of portal 1 to see what I can do.